# Infinite Loop, what is causing this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Order model I have:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :store_order_id, on: :create
before_validation :generate_id, on: :create if :manual_order?


def manual_order?
  order_type == "manual"
end

def generate_id
  begin
    self.store_order_id = "M-#{(SecureRandom.random_number(9e5) + 1e5).to_i}"
  end while self.class.find_by(store_order_id: store_order_id)
end
```

controller create method:

```
 def create
    @order = Order.new
    @order.order_type = "manual"

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save!
```

For some reason, this is causing a loop of the `:generate_id`

What is causing this?

I use similar code to generate a token for each order, the only difference is I don't use a `validates_uniquness_of` with it like i do for `:generate_id`.  But I don't see how this is causing this loop?

I do need the `validates_uniqueness_of :store_order_id, on: :create` because it's also used for webhook id's in case the webhook fires twice, which is does on occasion .  I do this to avoid multiple identical records.  Because of this uniqueness validaton, when I create manual orders it won't save because the store_order_id needs to be unique.  So i created the `generate_id` method, but with issues.

Assuming it was possible the uniquness was causing this, because there is no difference from code I have used many times, i tried:

`validates_uniqueness_of :store_order_id, on: :create unless :manual_order?`

but this didn't solve it.

Comment: You might be getting store_order_id nil in this line self.class.find_by(store_order_id: store_order_id). have you checked?

Comment: Do you have methods `store_order_id` or `store_order_id=` defined?

Comment: Seems store_order_id is an attribute on the model.